# Spring-security, Tomcat and SPNEGO - best approach

Tags: apache, tomcat, spring-security, kerberos, spnego

I'm looking for the best approach to achieve SPNEGO/Kerberos login for a spring-security application on Tomcat and Windows. Candidates i've looked at:

- [Spring Security Kerberos Extension](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/extensions/krb/index.html)
- Waffle
- Apache httpd fronting with [mod_auth_kerb](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/) module
- Apache httpd with mod_auth_sspi module

I wasn't super-impressed by Waffle and mod_auth_sspi only seems to support NTLMv1 so that is out. I do see a value in fronting with an Apache httpd so that seems like a good approach. How well does that play with spring-security though, I wonder. Who has done this? Which is the best/most stable approach?

Comment: Maybe that will give a hint for you... A while ago I was also looking for Tomcat+SPNEGO solution and ended with [these notes](http://centurion.nfors.com/w/software/tomcat#using_negotiate_authentication). Perhaps you'll find something useful there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do any overhead. Use the Spring SEC Extension. That one works quite well on our environment for more than a year. Though it has the potention for some improvement.